# Project euler 45

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm not yet a skilled programmer but I thought this was an interesting problem and I thought I'd give it a go.

> Triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal
>   numbers are generated by the following
>   formulae:
>
> - Triangle     T_(n)=n(n+1)/2 
>     1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...
> - Pentagonal     P_(n)=n(3n−1)/2     1, 5, 12, 22, 35,
>     ...
> - Hexagonal     H_(n)=n(2n−1)     1,
>     6, 15, 28, 45, ...
>
> It can be verified that T_(285) =
>   P_(165) = H_(143) = 40755.
>
> Find the next triangle number that is
>   also pentagonal and hexagonal.

Is the task description.

I know that Hexagonal numbers are a subset of triangle numbers which means that you only have to find a number where Hn=Pn.
But I can't seem to get my code to work. I only know java language which is why I'm having trouble finding a solution on the net womewhere. Anyway hope someone can help. Here's my code

```
public class NextNumber {

    public NextNumber() {
    next();
    }

    public void next() {


int n = 144;
int i = 165;
int p = i * (3 * i - 1) / 2;
int h = n * (2 * n - 1);
        while(p!=h) {
            n++;
           h = n * (2 * n - 1);

            if (h == p) {
                System.out.println("the next triangular number is" + h);
            } else {
                while (h > p) {
                    i++;
                    p = i * (3 * i - 1) / 2;
                }
                if (h == p) {
                    System.out.println("the next triangular number is" + h); break;
                    }
                 else if (p > h) {
                    System.out.println("bummer");
                }
            }

            }

    }
}
```

I realize it's probably a very slow and ineffecient code but that doesn't concern me much at this point I only care about finding the next number even if it would take my computer years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that T<sub>285</sub> = P<sub>165</sub> = H<sub>143</sub> = 40755. We start with `nt=286`, `np=166` and `nh=144` and work out the respective triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers. Whichever resulting number is smallest, we bump up its `n` value. Continue doing this until all numbers are equal and you have your answer.

A Python implementation of this algorithm runs in 0.1 seconds on my computer.

The problem with your code is overflow. While the answer fits into a 32 bit `int`, the temporary values `i * (3 * i - 1)` overflows before reaching the answer. Using 64 bit `long` values fixes your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it will produce the correct answer fairly quickly. The while loop can be simplified if you just print the result after the loop terminates:

```
while (p != h) {
    n++;
    h = n * (2 * n - 1);
    while (h > p) {
        i++;
        p = i * ((3 * i - 1) / 2);
    }
}
System.out.println("the next triangular number is" + h);
```

Note: your inner loop looks very much like the inner loop of my C++ solution. It produced the desired answer in about 0.002 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Okay. thx guys, don't know why my computer won't show me a result :) But nevertheless good to hear that it's not totally off.

Comment: @Peter: I checked and you may be having integer overflow when computing `p`. Notice the extra parentheses I have added in the expression `p = i * ((3 * i - 1) / 2)`. My code goes into an infinite loop if I remove the parentheses.

Comment: @Blast If `i` is even, then `3*i-1` is odd and `((3 * i - 1) / 2)` will round down by .5 due to integer arithmetic. You were just lucky in that it was odd for the final answer.

Comment: @marcog: Thanks for the correction, I'm going to go and fix my code.

Comment: Hmm that is probably the reason why it doesn't work. But apparently as you say it works in c++ so is it just java that has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that takes **2 ms**:

```
public class P45 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long H = 0;
        long i = 144;
        while(true) {
            H = i*((i<<1)-1);
            if ( isPentagonal(H) && isTriangle(H) ) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(H);
    }

    private static boolean isPentagonal(long x) {
        double n = (1 + Math.sqrt(24*x+1)) / 6;
        return n == (long)n;
    }

    private static boolean isTriangle(long x) {
        double n = (-1 + Math.sqrt((x<<3)+1)) / 2;
        return n == (long)n;
    }

}
```

**Improved**:

- You already specified that: hexagonal numbers are triangle numbers, but I add a short proof: `k*(2*k-1)` can be written in the following form `i*(i+1)/2` if `i = 2*k-1`.
- In this case `isTriangle` can be removed.
- The performance will be similar because that function was called seldom (it was called only when the number was pentagonal).

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.
The same works for project euler of Hackerrank

Answer (score 0):

---

### Math

The key is:

> ti = hi*2 - 1

where `ti` and `hi` are indices of T and H respectively.

That means for any `H(hi)`, there is always a `T(ti)`.
Thus only need to find the `P(pi)` = `H(hi)`, and that can be solved linear.

---

### Code (`go`)

- Solution:

  ```golang
  package p45

  // refer:   https://projecteuler.net/problem=45

  func NextAllEqual(startHi, startPi int32) (v int64, hi, pi int32) {
      start := calculateH(startHi)
      h, p := nextH(start, startHi), nextP(start, startPi)
      hi, pi = startHi+1, startPi+1

      for h != p {
          if hi <= 0 || pi <= 0 { // out of range,
              return -1, -1, -1
          }

          if h < p {
              h = nextH(h, hi)
              hi++
          } else {
              p = nextP(p, pi)
              pi++
          }
      }

      return h, hi, pi
  }

  // h(i) = i * (2*i - 1)
  func calculateH(i int32) int64 {
      return int64(i) * (int64(i)<<1 - 1)
  }

  // h(i+1) = h(i) + (4*i + 1)
  func nextH(h int64, i int32) int64 {
      return h + (int64(i)<<2 + 1)
  }

  // p(i+1) = p(i) + (3*i + 1)
  func nextP(p int64, i int32) int64 {
      return p + (3*int64(i) + 1)
  }

  // ti = 2*hi- 1
  func TQiFromHi(hi int32) int32 {
      return hi<<1 - 1
  }
  ```
- Test case:

  ```golang
  package p45

  import (
      "fmt"
      "testing"
  )

  const (
      zeroHi, zeroPi   = int32(1), int32(1)
      firstHi, firstPi = 143, 165
  )

  func TestNextAllEqual_first(t *testing.T) {
      // runOnce_NextAllEqual(t, zeroHi, zeroPi)
      runOnce_NextAllEqual(t, firstHi, firstPi)
  }

  func runOnce_NextAllEqual(t *testing.T, preHi, prePi int32) (v int64, hi, pi int32) {
      v, hi, pi = NextAllEqual(preHi, prePi)
      if v > 0 {
          ti := TQiFromHi(hi)
          fmt.Printf("v = %d, indices:\n\tti = %d, pi = %d, hi = %d\n\n", v, ti, pi, hi)

      } else {
          fmt.Println("Done, index out of range of int32")
      }

      return v, hi, pi
  }

  // find all with indices in range of int32,
  func TestNextAllEqual_all_int32_indices(t *testing.T) {
      hi, pi := zeroHi, zeroPi
      var v int64
      for seq := 1; ; seq++ {
          fmt.Printf("[%d]\t", seq)
          v, hi, pi = runOnce_NextAllEqual(t, hi, pi)
          if v <= 0 {
              break
          }
      }
  }
  ```

---

### Result

*(Run on an old laptop)*

- For problem 44:
  It took about `2ms`.

  ```
  === RUN   TestNextAllEqual_first
  v = 1533776805, indices:
      ti = 55385, pi = 31977, hi = 27693

  --- PASS: TestNextAllEqual_first (0.00s)
  ```
- To find all such indices within range of signed 32 bits.
  It took about `5.4s`, there are 4 such values, not including the start one `(1,1,1)`.

  ```
  === RUN   TestNextAllEqual_all_int32_indices
  [1] v = 40755, indices:
      ti = 285, pi = 165, hi = 143

  [2] v = 1533776805, indices:
      ti = 55385, pi = 31977, hi = 27693

  [3] v = 57722156241751, indices:
      ti = 10744501, pi = 6203341, hi = 5372251

  [4] v = 2172315626468283465, indices:
      ti = 2084377905, pi = 1203416145, hi = 1042188953

  [5] Done, index out of range of int32
  --- PASS: TestNextAllEqual_all_int32_indices (5.33s)
  ```