# Project Euler 45 in Java

Tags: java, project

The problem I am working on is: triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers are generated by the following formulae:

```
Triangle        Tn=n(n+1)/2     
Pentagonal      Pn=n(3n−1)/2    
Hexagonal       Hn=n(2n−1)
```

It can be verified that `T285 = P165 = H143 = 40755`.

Find the next triangle number that is also pentagonal and hexagonal.

I can't find out why my code is not working. It does work for the first number of `40755` but when running for the next one it just puts out `405939771`. Which is not correct according to the website.

```
boolean match = false;
System.out.println("What?");
//Calculations

for (int n = 180; match != true; n++) {
    //Pentagonal
    long Pn = n * (3 * n - 1) / 2;

    // Finding if it has a Hexagonal match
    for (int i = 144; i < n; i++) {
        long Hn = i * (2 * i - 1);
        if (Pn == Hn) {
            System.out.println(Hn);
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (match == true)
        break;
}
System.out.println("Done!");
```

I know there probably are much faster ways to do this but for now I am just getting too frustrated that it is not working and I cannot find out why.

Comment: You want to create a **real** [mcve]; so ideally a program that we can simply copy/paste/run; to get to the results that you *describe* here in an (unclear) way. But for starters: the puzzle is about having Tn = Pm = Ho with n, m, o being **different** numbers. You code only compares P and H ... where is T in that code?!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575723/project-euler-45?rq=1